# Showing solution of differential equation is zero given condition

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

This problem is from mitocw 18.034 pset #6:

a) Find the solution of the initial value problem
$y'' + y = Aδ(t − c), y(0) = a, y'(0) = b$, where A, a, b, c are constant and c > 0.

(b) Show that $y(t) = 0$ for $t ≥ c$ if and only if $y(c) = 0$ and
$A = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2},$ $a \sin c ≥ b\cos c$ or $A = − \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$, $a\sin c ≤ b\cos c$.
To interpret, these amplitudes A and locations of impulse c cancel the oscillation.

For part a) I took laplace transforms and got:
$Ly = \frac{Ae^{-sc} + as + b}{s^2 + 1}$ which gives the solution $y = Ah(t-c)sin(t-c) + a\cos t + b \sin t$ where $h(t)$ is the Heaviside function.

I'm confused how my answer for part a) can be used to show $y(t) = 0$ for $t\geq c$ given the conditions in part b).

Answer (score 1):

If $y(t) = 0$ for $t\geq 0$, then we have $A\sin t \cos c-A\cos t \sin c + a\cos t + b\sin t = 0$ which means $\sin t (b+A\cos c) + \cos t (a-A\sin c) = 0$ therefore $b+A\cos c = 0$ and $a - A \sin c = 0$. It is easy to see either $A = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ or $A = -\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$. In the former case, $a\sin c - b \cos c = A \geq 0$, similarly for the other case.

For the other direction, we have that $f(t) = 0$ is a solution of the differential equation for $t > c$, by uniqueness this solution must be unique (over $t > c$) so we must have $y(t) = 0$ for $t>c$. Adding on the condition $y(c) = 0$, we get the result as desired.